# MS SQL Server - How to generate end date for each line item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the table, I have `emp_id`, `rate_effective_date` and `hourly_rate columns`, however, there is no `rate_effective_end_date` column.

Please help me with a query that generate `rate_effective_end_date` for each line item.

The `rate_effective_end_date` will be calculated from next `rate_effective_date -1` for any given employee.

```
Emp id  | rate_effective_date | hourly_rate | rate_effective_end_date 
--------+---------------------+-------------+------------------------
1       | 01/01/17            | 50          | 06/29/17
1       | 06/30/17            | 55          | 09/30/17
1       | 10/01/17            | 45          | 12/31/17
1       | 01/01/18            | 60          | {null}
```

Comment: And how is `rate_effective_end_date` calculated?

Comment: How on earth could we even begin to answer this question without knowing what your data/logic is?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Have a read of this:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: My best guess is look up the [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions. But voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead()` function with `dateadd()` function

```
select *, 
       dateadd(day, -1, lead(rate_effective_date) over(partition by Emp_id order by rate_effective_date)) as rate_effective_end_date  
from table t;
```

In other way you could also use `subquery`

```
select *, 
       dateadd(day, -1, (select top 1 rate_effective_date from table 
                         where emp_id = t.emp_id and 
                         rate_effective_date > t.rate_effective_date 
                         order by rate_effective_date)
               ) as rate_effective_end_date  
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all fields from `myTable`, and where a given employee has another record with a later `rate_effective_date` will return `rate_effective_end_date` calculated as 1 day before the following record's `rate_effective_date`.
If there is no later record, the returned value will be null.

```
; with cte as 
(
    select emp_id
    , rate_effective_date 
    , hourly_rate 
    , row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by rate_effective_date ) r 
    from myTable
)

select a.emp_id
, a.rate_effective_date 
, a.hourly_rate 
, dateadd(day, -1, b.rate_effective_date) rate_effective_end_date 
from cte a
left outer join cte b
on b.emp_id = a.emp_id
and b.r = a.r + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4670/2)